# Best way to use rails console with cloud foundry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console, cloud-foundry

We've been experimenting with CF over Heroku and running into some issues.  One of them deals with accessing the rails console in a CF AI.  We're using Pivotal's PWS and have tried a number of things, including:

```
cd app; export HOME=$(pwd); source .profile.d/0_ruby.sh; rails c
```

and

```
cd app; export HOME=$(pwd); source .profile.d/*.sh; rails c
```

Both of which are hit or miss and typically don't work.

It seems a bit ridiculous that it's THIS much work to access the rails console via CF.  I feel like there has to be a better, faster way.

Does anyone have any tips?

For anyone saying we should `cf ssh` in, here is what happens:

```
vcap@2f4663e4-f876-490c-65e2-a498:~$ cd app
vcap@2f4663e4-f876-490c-65e2-a498:~/app$ ls .profile.d/000_multi-supply.sh  0_ruby.sh
vcap@2f4663e4-f876-490c-65e2-a498:~/app$ source .profile.d/0_ruby.sh
vcap@2f4663e4-f876-490c-65e2-a498:~/app$ cd ..
vcap@2f4663e4-f876-490c-65e2-a498:~$ rails c
bash: rails: command not found
vcap@2f4663e4-f876-490c-65e2-a498:~$ source app/.profile.d/000_multisupply.sh
vcap@2f4663e4-f876-490c-65e2-a498:~$ rails c
bash: rails: command not found
```

Comment: After you `cf ssh` into an application container, it's necessary to manually source the `profile.d` scripts (this is across the board for Cloud Foundry, not just PWS).  This happens automatically when your app runs, so manually doing this in your ssh session will give you the same env as your running app.  After that you *should* be able to run ruby & rails commands.  This doesn't seem to be the case for you, can you expand on what happens when it doesn't work?

Comment: For what it's worth, I believe you can also run the rails console locally.  See this post -> https://content.pivotal.io/blog/down-and-dirty-with-rails-on-cloud-foundry

Comment: @DanielMikusa after SSHing in, take a look:  vcap@2f4663e4-f876-490c-65e2-a498:~$ cd app
vcap@2f4663e4-f876-490c-65e2-a498:~/app$ ls .profile.d/
000_multi-supply.sh  0_ruby.sh
vcap@2f4663e4-f876-490c-65e2-a498:~/app$ source .profile.d/0_ruby.sh
vcap@2f4663e4-f876-490c-65e2-a498:~/app$ cd ..
vcap@2f4663e4-f876-490c-65e2-a498:~$ rails c
bash: rails: command not found
vcap@2f4663e4-f876-490c-65e2-a498:~$ source app/.profile.d/000_multi-supply.sh
vcap@2f4663e4-f876-490c-65e2-a498:~$ rails c
bash: rails: command not found

Comment: @DanielMikusa sorry for the formatting.  pasted it above in the question

Comment: CF does this weird thing with the home directory where it sets it to `/home/vcap/app` (not just `/home/vcap`) when your app runs.  As such, the scripts you need to source are written with that assumption.  Try `HOME=/home/vcap/app source .profile.d/000_multi-supply.sh` (not sure you strictly need to source this file), and `HOME=/home/vcap/app .profile.d/0_ruby.sh`.

Comment: Thanks @DanielMikusa.  Tried those as well as vcap@2f4663e4-f876-490c-65e2-a498:~$ HOME=/home/vcap/app app/.profile.d/0_ruby.sh
 from the home folder and get `bash: app/.profile.d/0_ruby.sh: Permission denied`

Comment: Try this, it's a new command a colleague showed me:  `cf ssh my-app -t -c "/tmp/lifecycle/launcher /home/vcap/app 'rails c' ''"`.

Comment: Holy crap that worked.  Amazing.  What's more unfortunate is that CF is suppose to make this stuff EASIER not harder.  So something like `cf console rails` should do the above.   Im also having issues with getting RDS to work with CF, so im quickly losing interest.  Thanks for the awesome help though!

Comment: Yea, this is an area that is not as smooth as it should be.  There's work in the backlog to improve it though.  It looks like the command I sent will get wrapped into a `run` command (or something like that), so you can `cf ssh` and `run rails c` or `cf ssh -c `run rails c`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of writing this, to fire up a Rails console run `cf ssh my-app -t -c "/tmp/lifecycle/launcher /home/vcap/app 'rails c' ''"`.

This will SSH into the container and use the lifecycle launcher, which sets up the environment for you, to execute the command.

Comment: Any way to do it without SSH and jus the the CF cli?  So I can retrieve a rails ENV variable?

Comment: This here would be ideal: https://content.pivotal.io/blog/cloud-foundry-now-supports-the-rails-console

Comment: If you want to run the rails console in your app environment, you need to be in your app environment. The only way to do that is to SSH into it. If you are just trying to get some information from the app, there maybe other ways. For example, if you want to see env variables then you can run `cf env`.

Comment: That article is pretty old, but I think it was running a tunnel behind the scenes for you (if I remember correctly caldecott was a tunnel). You could run an SSH tunnel here & run your rails console locally, if that's more helpful. `cf ssh` supports the standard ssh arguments for tunneling.